# weka - Draw Learning curve

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I'm trying to draw Learning curve for my models, the curve illustrate the relation between the error and the iteration number or some thing like this:

[image]

I read this post:
http://weka.wikispaces.com/Learning+curves

But i have several problems:

1. Can't get data from Database source
2. Can't get relation between error and iteration number
3. After analyze the dataset and select output format to "GNUplot" I can't save the image when I press save output and the test output shows:

```
(generate png:

set terminal png size 800,600

set output "plot.png"

replot)
```

Comment: you can find some description at weka wiki https://weka.wikispaces.com/Learning+curves

Comment: wikispaces.com is no longer....the links above are dead.

Answer (score -2):

This tutorial is pretty good [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArU4x0Lnwi4)

It explains all of the configuration details for creating your learning curve.
I will summarize:

- Open the experimenter
- choose advanced configuration mode
- destination: choose a convenient location, provide an arbitrary name.arff file name
- for result generator left click on the text box
- for split evaluator choose regression for regression or classification for classification
- for split evaluator left click on the text box
- for classifier choose: meta->filtteredClassifier
- left click the text box of the classifier
- for classifier: choose the classifier/predictor you want
- for filter: choose unsupervised->instances->remove percentage
- close all dialogue boxes
- for data sets choose a data set
- for generate properties select enabled
- choose the property split evaluator->classifier->remove percentages
- enter all the percentages of data you want to plot
- go to run tab
- click run
- go to analyze tab
- choose comparison field the error you want
- click preform test